# Using jQuery AJAX to update table of mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use jQuery AJAX to update table.
But AJAX only works for first time, the other requests were disappear.

javascript

```
function uploadItems(data, step, savetype) {                                                                                                                    
            data.append('step', step);                                                                                                                                                      data.append('savetype', savetype);                                                                                                                           
            data.append('new_store_id', store_id);                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                         
            $.ajax({                                                                                                                                                     
                url: "order_store_edit.php?store_id="+store_id,                                                                                                          
                type: "POST",                                                                                                                                            
                data: data,                                                                                                                                              
                contentType: false,                                                                                                                                      
                processData: false,                                                                                                                                      
                async: true                                                                                                                                              
            })                                                                                                                                                           
            .done(function(data)                                                                                                                                         
            {                                                                                                                                                            
                console.log(data);                                                                                                                                       
            })
            .fail(function(xhr, text_status, errorThrown)                                                                                                                
            {                                                                                                                                                            
                return false;                                                                                                                                            
            });                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

php

```
foreach ($set_item_arr as $i => $value) {                                                                                                                            
        order_item_up($item[$i]['item_id'], $value);                                                                                                                     
        echo $item[$i]['item_id'] . ' : ' . $value['disable'] . "\n";                                                                                                    
}
```

mysql

```
function order_item_up($item_id, $set_arr)                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                            
    if (! isset($item_id)) {                                                                                                                                                 
        echo 'no id';                                                                                                                                                        
        return;                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                        
    global $db;                                                                                                                                                              
    $sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET ';                                                                                                                                
    foreach ($set_arr as $key => $val) {                                                                                                                                     
        $sql .= $key."='".$val."', ";                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                        
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);                                                                                                                                              
    $sql .= " WHERE item_id = '$item_id'";                                                                                                                                   
    return $db->execute($sql);                                                                                                                                               
}
```

For example, I have twenty forms, and I append ten of them to one FormData, and then call uploadItems.
So it will send two times, but the update query only work for first time.

There is no error message show on, no in console, no in browser.

What is the probably reason of this problem?

**EDIT:**

Is it possible caused by Table-level lock? My engine is MyISAM.

**EDIT: Result of editing SQL query**

```
XHR finished loading: 
983 : 1 
984 : 1 
985 : 1 
986 : 1 
987 : 1 
988 : 1
989 : 1 
990 : 1 
991 : 1 
992 : 1

XHR finished loading:  
no id : 1 
no id : 1
```

As I mentioned, the second XHR failed to update database.

---

#### Solved

I found the problem ... I should use item_id instead of index of array, because the array size will be different after update database.

Answer (score 0):

```
function order_item_up($item_id, $set_arr)                                                                                                                                   
{    
    foreach ($set_arr as $key => $val) 
    {         
        $qry1="UPDATE tablename SET". $key."='".$val."' where $item_id='".$item_id."'";
        $re=mysql_query($qry1)or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

use this update section for no.of rows.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have tried that. But problem still there.
I have edit my post adding the XHR response.